# Add whitespace conditionally, based on flags

Tags: vimrc, statusline

I'm trying to add whitespace on the left side of the flags section, and to hide this whitespace when flags aren't exist.

Here is what I mean:

```
Statusline with no flags:
:File.txt                              text:
:------------------------------------------:

The same, with flags:
:File.ext                   text    [+][RO]:
:------------------------------------------:

Incorrect:
:File.ext                          text    :
:------------------------------------------:

Colons and hyphens are used to show window size.
```

And here is statusline code:

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline=
set statusline+=%t
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=%{strlen(&filetype)?&filetype:'text'}
"set statusline+=%{&modified?'\ \ \ \ ':''}             " Works
set statusline+=%{(&modified||&readonly)?'\ \ \ \ ':''} " Doesn't work
set statusline+=%m%r
```

As you can see, there is an issue with 7th line.

So, there are two questions:

- How to check condition against both flags?
- A better option: is there a way to check against *any* flag? If we have some arbitrary flag in statusline, then add whitespace; if we don't have flags, then don't add whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the pipe symbols, like:

```
set statusline+=%{(&modified\|\|&readonly)?'\ \ \ \ ':''} "
```

If it gets to complicated, you might consider to use a function to create the statusline:

```
function MyStatusLine()
    let sl = '%t%='
    if &filetype != ''
        let sl .= &filetype
    else
        let sl .= 'text'
    endif
    if &modified || &readonly
        let sl .= '    '
    endif
    let sl .= '%m%r'
    return sl
endfunc
set statusline=%!MyStatusLine()
```

---

Update:
The flags named in `:help stl`:

- `%m/%M` is `&modified`
- `%r/%R` is `&readonly`
- `%h/%H` is `&filetype == 'help'`
- `%w/%W` is `&previewwindow`

Comment: As I understand, checking against arbitrary flag will be quite complicated?

Comment: When I open help with `h: stl` and then scroll down to "item meaning", it is written that there are only 4 flags: modified (m, M), readonly (r, R), help buffer (h, H), and preview window (w, W). I mean any of them.

Comment: @jsv See update.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, today I discovered that described task could be solved differently: `set statusline+=%(\ \ \ \ %m%r%h%)`